# Rails: How do you sort a model by a column in a tabel two associations away?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, named-scope

The problem I'm having is like this:  The model to sort is SchoolClass which has_many Students which in turn has_many Projects and each project has an end_date.  I need to sort the SchoolClasses four ways:  First by the earliest project end_date sort ascending and descending, and second by the latest project end_date sort ascending and descending.  Does this make sense?

```
class SchoolClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  belongs_to :school_class
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
end
```

The only way I can think of doing it is very brute force and involves having a methods in the SchoolClass model that return the earliest and latest project dates for that instance like so:

```
students.collect(&:projects).flatten.select(&:end_date).sort.last
```

to find the latest project end_date for that class and then fetching out all the classes of the database and sorting them by that method.  Surely this is just awful though, right?  I would really like to find the rails way to get this ordering (with scopes maybe?).  I thought something like `SchoolClasses.joins(:students).joins(:projects).order('projects.end_date ASC')` might work but that will crash rails (and looking at it now the logic is wrong anyway i think).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sure.  A SchoolClass has a set of projects associated with it through the students.  The earliest end_date for a SchoolClass would be the ealiest end_date out of the set of end_dates belonging to that SchoolClass and the latest end_date the latest of those.  So these two dates can be thought of as virtual attributes of the SchoolClass and these are the values by which I would like to sort them.

Comment: Imagine then that there were three SchoolClasses, Class1, Class2, Class3 with earliest dates and latest dates like this (respectively) [1/1/11,1/5/11],[1/2/11,1/3/11],[1/3/11,1/4/11].  Sorted by earliest date ascending they are Class1, Class2, Class3.  Sorted by latest date ascending they are Class2,Class3,Class1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
scs = SchoolClass.joins({:students => :projects}).
  select("school_classes.id, 
          MIN(projects.end_date) AS earliest_end_date,
          MAX(projects.end_date) AS latest_end_date").
  group("school_classes.id").
  order("earliest_end_date ASC")
```

The objects in the `scs` array has following attributes:

- id
- earliest_end_date
- latest_end_date

If you need additional attributes you can do the following

1) Add the additional attributes to the `group` and `select` methods

2) Query the full SchoolClass object using the `id`

3) Rewrite the query to use a nested JOIN

```
scs = SchoolClass.joins(
"JOIN (
   SELECT a.id, 
          MIN(c.end_date) AS earliest_end_date, 
          MAX(c.end_date) AS latest_end_date
    FROM  school_classes a
    JOIN  students b ON b.class_id = a.id
    JOIN  projects c ON c.student_id = b.id
    GROUP BY a.id
 ) d ON d.id = school_classes.id
").select("school_classes.*, 
           d.earliest_end_date AS earliest_end_date, 
           d.latest_end_date AS latest_end_date").
  order("earliest_end_date ASC")
```

Comment: Updated my answer take a look